# Is a sword created by a Spiritbane Spike magical and +1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, equipment

A [Spiritbane Spike](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spiritbane%20spike), when used, "becomes a short sword with the [ghost touch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/ghost-touch/) weapon special ability". Normally, you can't make a weapon *ghost touch* without giving it at least a +1 enhancement bonus.

So, does the short sword creating in this way possess the +1 enhancement bonus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No

Items only do what they said they do. The Enchancement requirement is for weapons crafted one way or another - which is why it's under the "crafting" section in the rules.

However, you're not *crafting* this shortsword. This item is just transforming into a weapon with a special ability.